# Confusion about AverageTimer32 PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I'm trying to set up a `PerformanceCounter` to measure the average execution time of a certain method. I've tried to read up on `AverageTimer32` and I've looked at a lot of examples, but I just can't seem to get it right.

I set up the categories

```
CounterCreationDataCollection CCDC = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

// Add the counter.
CounterCreationData averageTimer32 = new CounterCreationData();
averageTimer32.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.AverageTimer32;
averageTimer32.CounterName = counterName;
CCDC.Add(averageTimer32);

// Add the base counter.
CounterCreationData averageTimer32Base = new CounterCreationData();
averageTimer32Base.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.AverageBase;
averageTimer32Base.CounterName = baseCounterName;
CCDC.Add(averageTimer32Base);

// Create the category.
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(categoryName, "Demonstrates usage of the AverageTimer32 performance counter type", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, CCDC);
```

Then I create the counters

```
PC = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName, false);

BPC = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, baseCounterName, false);

PC.RawValue = 0;
BPC.RawValue = 0;
```

And finally I log the elapsed time each time my method is called

```
private void TheMethodIWantToMeasure() {
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // Fake work that take ~50ms
    Thread.Sleep(50 + random.Next(-10, 10));

    stopwatch.Stop();

    PC.IncrementBy(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    BPC.Increment();
}
```

Doing like this, I end up with a result in performance monitor looking like this. I get spikes instead of a contious curve around 50 ms:
[image: Picture]

Have I misunderstood `AverageTimer32`? I've read about it, but it's a bit confusing. However, I have seen examples doing practically the same thing as me so I'm guessing it should work. What could be the reason that I only get spikes?

**Edit**
It might be worth mentioning that `TheMethodIWantToMeasure` only is called every ~5s, and I just realized that I get the spike every ~5th second. But I don't understand how that can affect the results if `AverageTimer32` uses the formula ((N 1 -N 0)/F)/(B 1 -B 0). It shouldn't depend on how often I store values for N and B?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer lies in the refresh / sample rate of your permon settings. If you were to take out your **~5s** interval or atleast change it to something like **~10ms**, you'll probably notice the graph looking a little more like you initially expected. Alternatively update your performance counter refresh rate to a higher interval (30 seconds) would be the same. (*Do this by right clicking on the perfMon graph -> properties -> General Tab -> Sampe Every x seconds*).

The reason is that perfMon refreshes every 1 second (by default) and then needs to display your average. So it takes "*all*" the operations you've added to your counters for that second and plots it on the graph.

**Example:** If you had *3* operations executing in a second (**0.1ms, 0.2ms & 0.3,ms**), perfMon will display your average to be **0.2ms**, which is correct.

Why the gaps? I believe it's because now after your average was calculated and you see your "Spike", the next second (when perfMon refreshes again), it will calculates the average of 0 operations in 0secs = 0.

My suggestion (if you want to truly see the average of how long your `TheMethodIWantToMeasure` takes on average to run, is to **take your ~5s interval out completely** and simply let the method continually run. That should do the trick.